# Reading specific number of bytes from a buffered reader in golang

Tags: go, bufferedreader, peek

I am aware of the specific function in golang from the **bufio** package.

```
func (b *Reader) Peek(n int) ([]byte, error)
```

> Peek returns the next n bytes **without advancing the reader**. The bytes
>   stop being valid at the next read call. If Peek returns fewer than n
>   bytes, it also returns an error explaining why the read is short. The
>   error is ErrBufferFull if n is larger than b's buffer size.

I need to be able to read a specific number of bytes from a Reader that **will advance the reader**.  Basically, identical to the function above, but it advances the reader.  Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Note that the `bufio.Read` method calls the underlying `io.Read` at most once, meaning that it can return `n < len(p)`, without reaching EOF. If you want to read exactly `len(p)` bytes or fail with an error, you can use `io.ReadFull` like this:

```
n, err := io.ReadFull(reader, p)
```

This works even if the reader is buffered.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Eliminates the nagging doubt of a "short" read i.e. no need to loop and check for io.EOF's etc.  Doc's have a great example here too:  https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull

Comment: Maybe it's worth noting that io.ReadFull is just a wrapper for this call: 

`io.ReadAtLeast(reader, p, len(p))`

Also in the case of `io.ReadFull` you should first define the `p` with its length equals to the size of bytes you want to read, but for `io.ReadAtLeast` the length of the `p` can be whatever as long as it's bigger than or equals to the size you want to read.

Comment: @sepehr is right. The question wording was "specific number of bytes", i.e if I understand the English right, that equals to "exact number of bytes". Besides, quite an actual question if you want to implement message framing over a stream. "Exact", or "specific", is not the same thing as "bigger than or equals". If I need exactly 4 bytes, then what if it will read 400? The question was about this, specifically.

Comment: Actually, io.LimitReader is only useful if you want to limit some code you don't control, e.g. some external library code. If it is your code, then there's no use of it, since it just calls a plain Read() _once_, which anyway can't read more than you requested. Now the thing, people are asking, and I was trying to find an answer: WHERE exactly it is told the read can't read more than requested? The answer is: NOWHERE. In the Linux docs, the underlying level, they say "usually", and "expected to". Anything in Go just don't say a word. Probably, for guys of Google that was way too obvious?

Comment: I mean, in other places people are suggesting using LimitReader, to limit the maximum number of bytes read. Actually, that's just a redundant safety net, as io.ReadFull() actually does the job, and reads _exactly_ the number you requested. Still, if you look at the source code, you will be infected with doubt, as @sepehr pointed out above. ))) What I miss is some tip in Read() docs, saying it actually can't read more than requested.

Answer (score 17):

```
func (b *Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
```

http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Read

The number of bytes read will be limited to `len(p)`

Comment: This will not 'always' read a specific number of bytes though, it will only limit the bytes read to len(p).

Comment: Also, it may not read at all. According to this solution, you might need to call `Read` repeatedly until you get the anticipated data. Not all readers are the same. This answer assumes that as if they are.

Answer (score 10):

TLDR:

```
my42bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(io.LimitReader(myReader, 42))
```

Full answer:

@monicuta mentioned `io.ReadFull` which works great. Here I provide another method. It works by chaining `ioutil.ReadAll` and `io.LimitReader` together. Let's read the doc first:

> ```
> $ go doc ioutil.ReadAll
> func ReadAll(r io.Reader) ([]byte, error)
>      ReadAll reads from r until an error or EOF and returns the data it read. A
>      successful call returns err == nil, not err == EOF. Because ReadAll is
>      defined to read from src until EOF, it does not treat an EOF from Read as an
>      error to be reported. 
>
> $ go doc io.LimitReader
> func LimitReader(r Reader, n int64) Reader
>      LimitReader returns a Reader that reads from r but stops with EOF after n
>      bytes. The underlying implementation is a *LimitedReader.
> ```

So if you want to get 42 bytes from `myReader`, you do this

```
import (
        "io"
        "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
        // myReader := ...
        my42bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(io.LimitReader(myReader, 42))
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        //...
}
```

Here is the equivalent code with `io.ReadFull`

> ```
> $ go doc io.ReadFull
> func ReadFull(r Reader, buf []byte) (n int, err error)
>     ReadFull reads exactly len(buf) bytes from r into buf. It returns the number
>     of bytes copied and an error if fewer bytes were read. The error is EOF only
>     if no bytes were read. If an EOF happens after reading some but not all the
>     bytes, ReadFull returns ErrUnexpectedEOF. On return, n == len(buf) if and
>     only if err == nil. If r returns an error having read at least len(buf)
>     bytes, the error is dropped.
> ```

```
import (
        "io"
)

func main() {
        // myReader := ...
        buf := make([]byte, 42)
        _, err := io.ReadFull(myReader, buf)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        //...
}
```

Compared to `io.ReadFull`, an advantage is that you don't need to manually make a `buf`, where `len(buf)` is the number of bytes you want to read, then pass `buf` as an argument when you Read

Instead you simply tell `io.LimitReader` you want at most 42 bytes from `myReader`, and call `ioutil.ReadAll` to read them all, returning the result as a slice of bytes. If successful, the returned slice is guaranteed to be of length 42.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, the slice will not be guaranteed to be of length 42 bytes. An io.Reader may return fewer bytes than requested. ReadFull will try to read as many bytes as you want, LimitReader will limit the bytes you're going to read. ReadFull simplifies handling the case when you want to really read N bytes.

Comment: ...or it will return an error (a good thing). + ReadAll already may make a buffer of a bigger size than you need.

Comment: This must be an accepted approach. Maybe a little rewording at the end would help, but otherwise it solves the problem and answers the question. I wonder why there's no straightforward function for this. Thanks @navigaid

Comment: Actually, io.LimitReader is only useful if you want to limit some code you don't control, e.g. some external library code. If it is your code, then there's no use of it, since it just calls a plain Read() _once_, which anyway can't read more than you requested. Now the thing, people are asking, and I was trying to find an answer: WHERE exactly it is told the read can't read more than requested? The answer is: NOWHERE. In the Linux docs, the underlying level, they say "usually", and "expected to". Anything in Go just don't say a word. Probably, for guys of Google that was way too obvious? ))))

Answer (score 3):

I am prefering Read() especially if you are going to read any type of files and it could be also useful in sending data in chunks, below is an example to show how it is used

```
fs, err := os.Open("fileName"); 

if err != nil{
    fmt.Println("error reading file")
    return
}

defer fs.Close()

reader := bufio.NewReader(fs)

buf := make([]byte, 1024)

for{
    v, _ := reader.Read(buf) //ReadString and ReadLine() also applicable or alternative

    if v == 0{
        return
    }
    //in case it is a string file, you could check its content here...
    fmt.Print(string(buf))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a n-bytes sized buffer to the reader.

Comment: This is not guarantee that all ```n``` bytes will be fetched by Read(). It could be less without EOF in some marginal cases causing floating error.

It's better to allocate buffer of exact size ```buf := make([]byte, n)``` and then
```io.ReadAtLeast(reader, buf, len(buf))```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the bytes from an `io.Reader` and into an `io.Writer`, then you can use [`io.CopyN`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#CopyN)

> CopyN copies n bytes (or until an error) from src to dst. It returns the number of bytes copied and the earliest error encountered while copying.
>
> **On return, written == n if and only if err == nil.**

```golang
written, err := io.CopyN(dst, src, n)
if err != nil {
    // We didn't read the desired number of bytes
} else {
   // We can proceed successfully
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To do this you just need to create a byte slice and [read](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Read) the data into this slice with

```
n := 512
buff := make([]byte, n)
fs.Read(buff)  // fs is your reader. Can be like this fs, _ := os.Open('file')
```

---

`func (b *Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)`

> Read reads data into p. It returns the number of bytes read into p.
>   The bytes are taken from at most one Read on the underlying Reader,
>   hence n may be less than len(p)