# Reading bytes into Go buffer with a fixed stride size

Tags: go

I'd like to read and process 1024 bytes at a time in my file given by filename. I don't understand how to construct the outer loop correctly, especially to accommodate the final stride in which the buffer will contain fewer than 1024 bytes

What I have tried:

```
fs, _ := os.Open(filename)
defer fs.Close()
n := 1024 // 1kb
buff := make([]byte, n)
for {
    buff = make([]byte, n) // is this initialized correctly?
    n1, err := fs.Read(buff)
    if err != nil {
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(err)
        break
    }
    fmt.Println("read n1 bytes...", n1)
    fmt.Println(buff)
}
```

I have seen the following resources:

- [Reading specific number of bytes from a buffered reader in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660864/reading-specific-number-of-bytes-from-a-buffered-reader-in-golang)
- [Read arbitrary amount of bytes into buffer Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24817494/read-arbitrary-amount-of-bytes-into-buffer-golang)
- [How to read a binary file in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514201/how-to-read-a-binary-file-in-go)
- [Working with raw bytes from a network in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814408/working-with-raw-bytes-from-a-network-in-go)
- https://gobyexample.com/reading-files
- [Writing into fixed size Buffers in Golang with offsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639859/writing-into-fixed-size-buffers-in-golang-with-offsets)
- https://rwinslow.com/posts/use-flatbuffers-in-golang/
- [reading file line by line in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757389/reading-file-line-by-line-in-go)
- [How do I read in a large flat file in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313133/how-do-i-read-in-a-large-flat-file-in-golang)
- https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Reading bytes into Go buffer with a fixed stride size
>
> read and process 1024 bytes at a time in my file given by filename.
>
> accommodate the final stride in which the buffer will contain fewer
>   than 1024 bytes.

---

For number of bytes read guarantees, use `ioutil.ReadFull`. For efficient stream reads, use `bufio.Reader`. For efficiency, allocate the read buffer once and reuse it.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    stride := 1024
    filename := testname(stride)

    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    r := bufio.NewReader(f)
    buf := make([]byte, 0, stride)
    for {
        n, err := io.ReadFull(r, buf[:cap(buf)])
        buf = buf[:n]
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            if err != io.ErrUnexpectedEOF {
                fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
                break
            }
        }

        fmt.Println("read n bytes...", n)
        // process buf
    }
}

func testname(stride int) string {
    f, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "test.stride.")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    _, err = f.Write(make([]byte, 2*stride+stride/2))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return f.Name()
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/iYOY-z7hkoz

Output:

```
read n bytes... 1024
read n bytes... 1024
read n bytes... 512
```

Comment: Should I still use a Buffer if I know the exact size of the stream?